# Initialization of an empty Bash indexed array

Tags: arrays, bash, initialization

I’ve read some of the related questions on the subject but didn’t find the precise one I have in mind. I hope it’s not because it is too stupid.

In Bash 5 (5.2.15 if that matters), does it make any difference declaring an array like:

```
declare -a foo
```

compared with:

```
declare -a foo=()
```

I wonder if the first declaration does ensure the creation of an empty array, or only the second one guarantees that?

You may ask, what the point in initializing an empty array? Why not initializing it only when it’s needed storing a first element?

Well, I don’t know, maybe?

Then another question arises, would it be safe to initialize the array only when storing the first element with the append operator? Like:

```
bar+=('baz')
```

(*bar* here being not defined before this first element is appended)

it seems not to be a problem, even if option nounset is set, but doing so, am I assured 'baz' will always be the first element in the array? Is it safe to do that?

Also, in the case I’d need to change the default scope of the variable, I guess I couldn’t avoid using `declare` (or `local`), and it seems wrong to call declare or local every times I append an element (while it seems to work though).

Sorry if it’s a stupid question or is badly worded.

Have a nice day.

Comment: elements / entire arrays are created as required but it makes a difference if you try something like `myvar+=(["RANDOM"]=3)`; bash assumes indexed unless `declare -A myvar` was done beforehand

Comment: also variables are assumed global unless `local` or `declare` in a function is used

Comment: what is your definition of "the first element"? consider `unset v; v+=(1); v+=(2); unset v[0]`

Comment: Thx @jhnc good to know about your first comment, I’d have thought it assumes an associative array then…
I know for the default scope but what if I need to change it (declare a global variable from within a function)? Wouldn’t be an issue if the declare/local keyword is re-used for every element added?

Comment: you declare the array, not the elements. if you want global, don't use `declare`. but read the manul re dynamic scoping

Comment: `unset v; v+=(1); v+=(2); unset v[0]` I would have stupidly thought 2 would get the index 0 after the second unset… Thx again! ^^ Well, think I have to keep in mind "first element" isn’t forcibly the 0 index element.

Comment: @jhnc: about dynamic scoping: I guess `declare -g` is only useful to re-define the scope of a variable inside a function (ie: to make global a variable which was previously defined as local) (?). Because, as you wrote, without any keyword, the variable which is defined in a function will be global. OR, I see a second case, if the variable needs to be defined as integer or readonly, and global, then, because  declare is used, the `-g` becomes useful?

Comment: yes, I'd actually forgotten about `-g`. if you're nested a few levels deep and something higher declared a local, `-g` undoes the shadowing: `v=10; f(){ local v=1; g; }; g(){ v=2; }; f; declare -p v` vs same with `declare -g` in g

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Addressing the `declare -a foo` vs `declare -a foo=()` (vs `foo=()`) question ...

The results are going to depend on what's in `foo` prior to the `declare -a`.

```
$ foo=a                                       # set to single character
$ declare -p foo
declare -- foo="a"

$ declare -a foo                              # convert to array
$ declare -p foo
declare -a foo=([0]="a")                      # maintains initial value of 'a'


---------------------------------

$ foo=a                                       # set to single character
$ declare -p foo
declare -- foo="a"

$ declare -a foo=()                           # convert to array but also clear contents
$ declare -p foo
declare -a foo=()                             # array is empty


---------------------------------

$ foo=(a b c)                                 # set to 3 element array
$ declare -p foo
declare -a foo=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c")

$ declare -a foo                              # (re)declare as array
$ declare -p foo
declare -a foo=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c")      # maintains intitial set of 3 values


---------------------------------

$ foo=(a b c)                                 # set to 3 element array
$ declare -p foo
declare -a foo=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c")

$ declare -a foo=()                           # (re)declare as array but also clear contents
$ declare -p foo
declare -a foo=()                             # array is empty
```

Findings:

- if `foo` is undefined then `declare -a foo`, `declare -a foo=()` and `foo=()` behave the same
- if `foo` is predefined then `declare -a foo` will maintain the predefined value, while `declare -a foo=()` and `foo=()` will clear the contents of `foo`

If you know with 100% certainty your variable (`foo` in this case) is undefined then you're safe with `declare -a foo` or `declare -a foo=()` or `foo=()`.

If you're not sure about the contents of the variable (eg, it was exported by the parent process) then you're safer explicitly clearing the variable with `declare -a foo=()` or `foo=()`.

If you need the array to be empty then I'd suggest always *explicitly* defining the array as empty via `declare -a foo=()` or `foo=()`.

**NOTES:**

- results of these test cases will vary if you initially define `foo` and then try to define as an associative array (`declare -A foo`)
- personally, I prefer to initially run `unset foo` as this eliminates any unwanted leftover behavior from other `declare` flags (eg, `-x`, `-r`, etc), and *then* `declare` and populate the variable
- in the case of `foo=(a b c); declare -A foo` you'll generate an error since `bash` won't convert an 'indexed' array to an associative array ... a good example where `unset foo` should be run before creating/populating (a new) `foo`

Comment: It's important to note that this redeclaring behavior is completely different when `declare` is used inside a function since the values are reset there.